# SBT task timings publishing to Prometheus

Tags: sbt, prometheus, metrics, exporter

SBT can dump task timings `-Dsbt.task.timings=true`
However is it possible to hook a SBT task that additionally consumes timings?

For instance I would like to publish these metrics to either some exporter process (that is scraped by Prometheus) or directly to Prometheus gateway
I dont' want to be restricted to file dumping only